# 2-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector

When I create a 2-dimensional vector in c++ such as

`vector < vector<int> > matrix(3, vector<int>(4));`

would matrix[2][3] be accessible or would matrix[3][2] be accessible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created the first dimension as 3 and the second as 4. That means that `matrix[3]` is out of bounds. The other way around, though, would be fine- and would be fine *regardless* of which is which.

Answer (score 0):

`matrix[3][2]` does not make sense since you have defined your matrix as 3x4 and you're trying to access element `(4,3)`. If your question is regarding the access syntax, it's `matrix[row_no][col_no]` where the indices start from 0.